# llvm - get the first instruction of the basic block referred to in the label field of instruction of type br

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, control-flow, control-flow-graph, llvm-3.0

I'm trying to write a pass that will check the control flow of a code. Given a br instruction, I need to access the basic blocks referred to in the label fields.

For example, for the code:

```
 for(i = 0; i < count; i++){
    sum = add(sum, array[i]);
  }
```

I get the IR representation

```
br i1 %cmp, label %for.body, label %for.end
```

Now when I come across this instruction in the pass, I need to know exactly where these labels are pointing to. Can anybody please tell me how I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `->getOperand(1)` and `->getOperand(2)` methods for that instruction. This would give you 1st and 2nd BB respectively. See http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1User.html#abe1de1520a21f77ac57cc210bf0fb0b4

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That works too but I'm instead using BranchInst* branch = cast<BranchInst>(I); for (unsigned II = 0, NSucc = branch->getNumSuccessors(); II < NSucc; ++II) 
       {
        BasicBlock *Succ = branch->getSuccessor(II);}

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting, I'm new to SO and I don't know how to format code in the comments.